# What is the proper way to format different classes under each other in css?

Tags: html, css

So here is an HTML snippet- what I have in mind is each of these buttons' background image changing upon hover. But I think I don't have the right class setup here. I've read a lot of confusing articles about how to determine divs from classes and things like that, but really my idea of it is very messy, so I imagine my code is not ideal.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="option graphic">
GRAPHIC DESIGN
</div>

<div class = "option product">
PRODUCT DESIGN
</div>

<div class = "option web">
WEB DESIGN
</div>

<div class = "option design">
APP DESIGN
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.option{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 813px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #383838;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.option.graphic{
    background-image: "graphicdesign_1.png";
}
.option.graphic:hover{
    background-image: "graphicdesign_2.png";
}
```

What is the proper way to format these classes in HTML and CSS? What I have now is not working. Also if you could direct me to some good articles I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think your code is right, so are you sure about link of images ?

Comment: What is not working?  Everything seems fine.  One thing to note: if a div is unique, you can give it an ID.  It might be easier to call it with CSS or javascript.

Comment: background-image: url('graphicdesign_1.png'); And make sure that you have the right path!

Comment: "Not working" does not clarify the problem. If the problem is the lack of images, then @tilda has the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
background-image: "graphicdesign_1.png";
```

to

```
background-image: url("graphicdesign_1.png");
```

for both images

Comment: @Gert B. Op wants to change on hover "So here is an HTML snippet- what I have in mind is each of these buttons' background image changing upon hover"

Comment: @kevpoccs with pleasure

Comment: @JHuangweb I Think with the correct say the Op code will works fine